# How can I put a navbar on the right side of the screen and after on the top with Bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have put some content on the left of the screen and a navbar on the right side.

This is the code (simplified):

```
<div class="row" align="center">
            <div class = "col-md-12">
                <div class = "container">
                    <div class = "row">
                        <div class = "col-md-9">
                            //Here some content
                        </div>
                        <div class = "col-lg-2 col-md-3">
                            <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-collapse">
                              <div class="container-fluid">
                                  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                                    <li><a href="#">option1</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">option2</a></li>
                                    <li class="dropdown">
                                      <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">option3 <span class="caret"></span></a>
                                      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                        <li><a href="#">number1</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">number2</a></li>
                                      </ul>
                                    </li>
                                    <li><a href="#">option4</a></li>
                                  </ul>
                              </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
                            </nav>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
</div>
```

and it is displayed like this on big and medium screens (`col-lg` and `col-md`):

```
[THE CONTENT][THE NAVBAR]
```

but when I make my screen smaller my `navbar` goes to the bottom of the screen, under the content.

```
[THE CONTENT]
[THE NAVBAR]
```

What I want it is to allocate the navbar on the top of the screen (above the content) when I make my screen smaller (`col-sm` and `col-xs`) instead of the bottom side. Like this:

```
[THE NAVBAR]
[THE CONTENT]
```

Is it possible? How can I achieve it?

**P.S:** According to `Igor Ivancha` answer I tried with:

```
<div class="col-sm-9 col-sm-push-3">
   //Here some content
</div>
<div class="col-sm-3 col-sm-pull-9">
   //Here the navbar
</div>
```

but it also does not work.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to change the order of the grid columns, Bootstrap has `-pull-*` and `-push-*` classes:

```
<div class = "col-md-3 col-md-push-9">
  //Here navbar
</div>

<div class = "col-md-9 col-md-pull-3">
  //Here some content
</div>
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Igor_Ivancha/fnjmsrx2/1/)

Comment: But in both cases you provided the navbar it is on the left of the content and when you make it smaller the navbar goes to the bottom. You are getting the same behaviour I got. I need that the navbar will be on the right side and on smallers screens it will be on the top.

Answer (score 1):

Igor basically had it but reversed the order of divs and "push/pull" classes.

```
<div class = "col-md-3 col-md-push-9">
  //Here navbar
</div>

<div class = "col-md-9 col-md-pull-3">
  //Here some content
</div>
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1vt5qfnn/)

Comment: Thanks for correct Igor answer. Also a bit of rep for you ;)

Answer (score 0):

Add ID's to the column before navbar and the content

```
    <div class="col-md-9" id="theContent">
    ...
    <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-3" id="theNavbar">
    ...
```

Then add some jQuery to move them:

```
 if ($(window).width() <= 997) {
    $('#theNavbar').insertBefore($('#theContent'));
  }

  if ($(window).width() > 997) {
    $('#theNavbar').insertAfter($('#theContent'));
  }
```

**[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/17mLz6m4/1/)**

Edit: Updated the jsfiddle

Comment: But the navbar does not put on the right side on big screens.

Comment: In JSfiddle, make the Output box wider and hit Run again, it will work but has to be bigger than 997px. Again, not perfect but works on load.

Comment: Check my update, works now. Just moved the ID to the column div before the navbar